# Android App Bundle platform-specific module

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-app-bundle

I'd like to add a custom functionality to my app that is only available for some specific set of the Android API versions. This functionality requires a custom **uses-library** declaration in the module's manifest.

So I have

- Main App (API 21-27)
- Feature Legacy (API 21-26 and custom uses-library declaration)
- Feature New (API 27)

Is it possible to achieve above with the Android App Bundle ?
I've created custom 'dynamic-feature' modules for the "Feature Legacy" and "Feature New" but it looks like bundletool merges all the manifests across the used dynamic-feature modules and puts them into the *base* application. So I'm not able to launch the app on the Android 27 device because of the unfulfilled uses-library declaration. Also it's not possible to change minSdkVersion (27) for the module B, due to the manifest merge issues.

EDIT:
I know it is possible to create mutiple APKs with different flavours - but my goal is to have single, easy to distribute package.

Answer (score 2):

"ordinary", one wouldn't use modules for that, because the result will always be `1` merged `Mainfest.xml`. one probably would add an interface class, which is being implemented by two further classes - one targeting API `21-26` and the other one targeting API `27+`.

while with [App Bundles](http://g.co/androidappbundle) your goal of one single APK is not realistic, because it circumvents the whole idea of dynamic delivery. there's a plugin for the feature modules, which permits configuring the splits:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
```

and there are different configurations for a  [Dynamic Feature Manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure#dynamic_feature_manifest) (for such modules) in particlar `dist:onDemand="true"` and `android:isFeatureSplit="true"` are relevant here, combined with `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in the modules' `build.gradle`.

Comment: What about uses-library declaration ? I need to have it only for the API 21-26, but due to the changes in the API 27 it needs to be removed

Comment: So basically, what I'm trying to achieve is - different manifest entries depending on the API version.

Comment: @zenob it might be one base application, which subsequently installs either the legacy or actual version of a feature module... which are not contained in the base APK.

Comment: Hi @Martin, sorry I didn't mention it clearly but this is what I actually did - I created  dynamic-feature modules (and not  the regular *.library ones) so I would expect that all the dynamic-feature manifest entries should be put only to that specific component - surprisingly the base AndroidManifest also contains entries from all the dynamic-features

Comment: @zendo just found the relevant bug-tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:398856%20status:open
... while API level splitting apparently does not seem to be configurable; you could still have a base application and one single feature module (which handles the API levels by itself - eventually even with product flavors)... this might be worth a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily achievable with the use of Android flavors whereby module A and B are separated according to their API.

As it's different builds, you could specify for module B to have a different minSdkVersion than module A.

Comment: Hi @XepterX, my goal is to have single, easy to distribute package, and that's why I want to use app bundle